# How can I include meta tags in my R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, meta-tags

I tried adding the following, but the published app doesn't seem to include my meta tags. The source code shows that the stuff inside of the head tags appears to be default content. I'd like to make my app searchable.

```
tags$head(
  tags$meta(charset="UTF-8"),
  tags$meta(name="description", content="..."),
  tags$meta(name="keywords", content="..."),
  tags$meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
)

ui<-fluidPage(...)
```

Comment: Are you putting the `tags$head()` inside the `fluidPage()`? Because that should work (it adds those meta tags for me). Or are you trying to define them outside your `ui` object as you've done in the above example?

Comment: Yes, I just tried putting them inside fluidPage() and it works. I had noticed before from the source code that fluidPage was treated as a div. So I thought the head tag should be placed above that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make sure you include the meta tags **in** the `fluidPage` object. Shiny will pull out all the tags in the `head` to the appropriate place.

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$meta(charset="UTF-8"),
    tags$meta(name="description", content="..."),
    tags$meta(name="keywords", content="..."),
    tags$meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
  ), ...)
```